# Array index out of bounds exception android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the data from database table via php file and displaying it in android. In php file I seperated each column with "#".
So now I am getting values like 4#2012-11-06#test1#test2. But for some columns there is not data. So the values are comng like 5###.
Here when I splitting with # and displaying the data it is throwing out of bounds exception. How can I resolve this issue?

Code:

```
String st="1#2012-10-30#test1@2#2012-10-30#test2@3#2012-11-06#test3@9##test1@21##@22##@23##@";
    String[] val = st.trim().split("@");

for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++)
        {
            String str = val[i];

            String arr[] = str.split("#");
                  System.out.println("arr0" + arr[0]);
            System.out.println("arr1" + arr[1]);
            System.out.println("arr2" + arr[2]);
}
```

Comment: Post some code and post error logcat so we can help you more.

Comment: arr[2] not always exists

Comment: From php you can easily use json instead of '#' and on your client convert to json object by one line(for json you also have a nice lib gson from google)

Answer (score 2):

try as using [Pattern.compile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to split your current string :

```
String your_string = "4#2012-11-06#test1#test2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#");
String[] strarray =pattern.split(your_string);
```

for Handling if array index contain empty string change your code as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++)
        {
    String your_string =val[i];
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#");
    String[] strarray =pattern.split(your_string);

     for(int j=0;j<strarray.length;j++){
       if(strarray[j].trim().length() >0){

        System.out.println("arr"+j+"::" + strarray[j]);
       }
      else{

       }
     }
}
```

Comment: see my edit answer for handling null you must check array index if it contain null or any other value before using it

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(arr[0]) more safety :) or for printing you can use for loop (index < arr.length)